# removing outline from bootstrap button adds margin to buttons

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to do something that normally would seem simple, but for some reason it's giving me a headache. I have code that displays text on left side, and 2 button on the right side of the div.

I'm using bootstrap icons. By default they show up inside a black border, which looks ugly.

So when I try to remove the outline, for some reasons there seems to be more margin around the buttons. Basically the formatting looks off. I would hope that removing the Outline from the buttons would do only that.

```css
btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div style="display:flex; width:300px;">
  <h5>Text</h5>

  <div style="display:flex; margin-left:auto ">
    <button title="Edit Links" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
       <i class="bi bi-gear-fill"></i>
    </button>

    <button title="Expand/Collapse" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
       <i class="bi bi-arrows-expand"></i>
    </button>
    
    <div></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

so attached code has the CSS applied to remove outline. However, if I were to remove the CSS for class="btn" then its clearly visible that the buttons are positioned differently.

Essentially my goal is for the buttons to be much closer to each other.
Any pointers?

Below code is what it looks like with No CSS

```css
btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div style="display:flex; width:300px;">
  <h5>Text</h5>

  <div style="display:flex; margin-left:auto ">
    <button title="Edit Links" class="btn1" type="button">
       <i class="bi bi-gear-fill"></i>
    </button>

    <button title="Expand/Collapse" class="btn1" type="button">
       <i class="bi bi-arrows-expand"></i>
    </button>

    <div></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I fixed your heading tags, which didn't match. There are still unclosed div elements in your snippets.

Comment: If your goal is to move the buttons, messing with outline isn't the solution. Those outlines serve an important purpose and usually shouldn't be removed. It's not clear what you're trying to do, though. Bootstrap buttons are the size they are so they're adequate touch targets on mobile. You can use smaller [sizes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#sizes) if you like. What are you actually after?

Comment: I can't reproduce the black border you mention, either. Note that any [Bootstrap button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#examples) should have more than one class on it. Be sure you're following the docs correctly.

Comment: @isherwood if you look at the 2nd snippet you can see the border

Comment: I would like the buttons to be closer to each other as right now there is a pretty big gap

Comment: I added button theme classes to your first snippet to give them background color. As you can see, the buttons are tight together. Again, it's not clear what you want here.

Answer (score -1):

**You can't change it as it is by default** and when you add margin and padding to 0 it looks odd when active or focused such as this:

[image]